# ArcGIS tiles on OpenLayers are very blurry

Tags: arcgis-server, openlayers, coordinate-system

I'm trying to get [this map](http://services.geodataonline.no/arcgis/rest/services/Geocache_UTM33_EUREF89/GeocacheBasis/MapServer?f=jsapi) on my openlayers map

When I just add the layer in the code below, I do get the tiles, correctly referenced, but very blurry.

```
var url = "http://services.geodataonline.no/arcgis/rest/services/Geocache_UTM33_EUREF89/GeocacheBasis/MapServer";
layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
    url: url
  })
});
```

The ArcGISRest seems to request tiles from the wrong zoom level. Is there a way to get tiles of a higher zoom level?

I've tried to switch to ol.source.XYZ too (see below for the source definition), then it does show good quality tiles, but I can't get it to use the right projection (changing the projection option actually doesn't change the map).

```
source: new ol.source.XYZ({
  attributions: ["Kartverket, Geovekst og Kommuner - Geodata AS"],
  url: url + "/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}",
  projection: ol.proj.get("EPSG:25833"),
})
```

Here's the layers meta-information: http://services.geodataonline.no/arcgis/rest/services/Geocache_UTM33_EUREF89/GeocacheBasis/MapServer

Could someone help me with either the projection issue in the source.XYZ layer, or the quality issue in the TileArcGISRest layer?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of searching, I came up with a solution on my own. My problem was twofold:

First, I didn't load proj4js and the projection definition I needed. That's why changing the projection didn't alter the the map view at all.

When I had the projection, I could solve it by setting the map projection to EPSG:25833 with the TileArcGISRest tile source. Setting the map projection caused better tiles to be loaded.

I still didn't succeed in setting the correct parameters for the XYZ source, but that's not needed anymore.